# PHP get minDateTime from array

Tags: php, static

I've written a function to get the smallest date from an date[ ] and check for null.
If null == infinity

```
    /**
     * @param DateTimeInterface|null ...$dates
     * @return DateTime|null
     */
    public static function minDateTime(?DateTimeInterface ...$dates)
    {
        $dateList = [];
        $dates = array_filter($dates);
        if (empty($dates)) {
            // all values where null
            return null;
        }

        foreach ($dates as $date) {
            $dateList[] = $date->getTimestamp();
        }

        return (new DateTime())->setTimeStamp(min($dateList));
    }
```

Its working but could this be written smaller or with more comments, so that external coworkers can read this?

Comment: The `$dateList = [];` at the start of the function isn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to be aware of:

- `array_filter()` does a full loop of the array.
- `foreach()`, of course, does a full loop of the array.
- `min()` does a full loop of the array.
- `empty()` does a couple of things: it checks if a variable is not set AND if it is "falsey".  Because the `$dates` variable will be unconditionally set, there is no need to check this -- just use `!$dates` if you want to check if the array is empty.
- `array_filter()`, like `empty()` is a "greedy" seeker of "falsey" values.  I assume that this is a non-issue for your task because there should be no `0` or `false` (etc.) values -- only datetime values or `null`s.
- [datetime objects can be compared](https://stackoverflow.com/q/961074/2943403).
- you don't need to make iterated calls to `getTimestamp()`, nor do you need to declare a new datetime object and set its time manually -- just use the one you found.

I suppose I'll recommend that you loop the data just one time.  No array generation, no function calls, very direct and concise.  Your custom method name is descriptive.  Go with this:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nFLpk))

```
public static function minDateTime(?DateTimeInterface ...$dates)
{
    $minDate = null;
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        if ($date && (!$minDate || $date < $minDate)) {
            $minDate = $date;
        }
    }
    return $minDate;
}
```

Comment: This was really helpfull. Didn't know until now that null == false. That did not cross my mind for years. Thanks for additional information on the different loops, too!